# Add inner mapper to AutoMapper mapping profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to map an object of type source to destination and it has some inner mappings needed. I've created a custom mapper like this.

```
public class CustomerMappingProfile : ITypeConverter<Customer, CustomerDTO>
    {
        public CustomerDTO Convert(Customer input, CustomerDTO destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var CustomerDTO = new ObjectMapper<CustomerDTO, Customer>().Apply(input);
            CustomerDTO.NumbOfSeniorYears = input.YearsList != null ? input.YearsList.Count(p => p.Seniority == SeniorityEnum.Senior) : 0;
            CustomerDTO.NumOfYears = input.NumOfYears.Count();
            CustomerDTO.SearchTypeSelection = input.SearchTypeSelection;
            CustomerDTO.UpgradeTypes = input.UpgradeTypes;
            if (input.Rewards.Any())
            {
                foreach (var reward in input.Rewards)
                {
                    var result = Mapper.Map<Customer.Rewards, RewardsDTO>(reward);
                    CustomerDTO.Rewards.Add(result);
                }
            }
            if (input.EliteLevel == -1)
            {
                CustomerDTO.EliteLevel = null;
            }
            else
            {
                CustomerDTO.EliteLevel = input.EliteLevel;
            }
            var softLoggedIn = Helper.Util.PersServicesUtil.GetCharacteristic(input.Characteristics, "SOFT_LOGGED_IN");
            if (softLoggedIn != null)
            {
                if (softLoggedIn.Equals("true"))
                {
                    CustomerDTO.SoftLoginIndicator = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomerDTO.SoftLoginIndicator = false;
                }
            }
            CustomerDTO.SessionId = Customer.SessionId.ToLower();
            return CustomerDTO;
        }


    }
```

And I created Mapping profile

```
  public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Rewards, RewardsDTO>();
            CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>().ConvertUsing(new CustomerMappingProfile());;
        }
    }
```

And Injected the mapping profile into startup.cs

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });

            services.AddSingleton(sp => config.CreateMapper());
```

But I'm getting exception `InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.`  at Inner mapping with in the custom mapper at line `Mapper.Map<Customer.Rewards, RewardsDTO>(reward);`

Any idea on how to add inner mapping?

Comment: You are asking for a mapper of types <CustomerDTO, Customer>, but you have defined a mapper of type <Customer, CustomerDTO>

Comment: Also all of that logic should be defined in the mapping profile

Comment: @JSON can you explain what do you mean by define the logic in mapping profile.

Comment: Just create separate map for each type and automapper will work out which map to use if your type has inner complex types.

Comment: What is your `AutoMapper` version? I got complier error for this line `new ObjectMapper<CustomerDTO, Customer>().Apply(input);`. Share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive all your problems can be resolved by writing proper AutoMapper configuration.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Rewards, RewardsDTO>();
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.NumbOfSeniorYears, options =>
                options.MapFrom(source => source.YearsList.Count(p => p.Seniority == SeniorityEnum.Senior)))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.NumOfYears, options =>
                options.MapFrom(source => source.NumOfYears.Count()))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.EliteLevel, options =>
                options.Condition(source => source.EliteLevel != -1))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.SoftLoginIndicator, options =>
                options.MapFrom((source, dest, context) =>
                    Helper.Util.PersServicesUtil
                        .GetCharacteristic(source.Characteristics, "SOFT_LOGGED_IN")
                        ?.Equals("true") ?? false))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.SessionId, options =>
                options.MapFrom(source => source.SessionId.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

Judging by your code, I think you are mixing things up, for example concept of mapping profiles with the concept of type converters. You also do not have to map explicitly members that would be mapped anyway (`SearchTypeSelection` or `UpgradeTypes`).

I strongly suggest taking a trip to AutoMapper [documentation site](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#), so you can build for yourself solid knowledge fundamentals. Having that your mapping code will be more efficient and way shorter for you to write.

And one more thing. IMHO your injection logic looks weird. Have you asked yourself do you really need that custom singleton for AutoMapper? Why not just call `AddAutoMapper()`? See [documentation](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core) examples on how to work with AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: That null check for `YearsList` is not needed, it's built in.

Comment: You're right. Thanks again Lucian for valuable feedback. I updated my answer.